# How to find sum of factorial of 1,2,.....up to n(input no. )

Tags: c

I tried to solve this question many time but i am confused with the loop operation ..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
   int n,i,j, fact =1, sum =0;
   printf("Enter the limit of the factorial series");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
       for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
       {
          fact = fact * j;
       }
       sum = sum + fact;
       fact = 1;           
   }
   printf("The sum of the factorial series of % d terms is: %d",n,sum);
   getch();
}
```

Please give me a hint to solve the problem.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Do not try to write multi-language source files. Stick with one of C or C++ or Java.

Comment: variable overflow may be.., looks like an XY problem

Comment: Offtopic, but `void main` is wrong. Moreover avoid `conio.h` and `getch` as these are not standard.

Comment: you want to do this is java or c++? Here you have pasted c++ code.

Comment: factorial of 13 is `6227020800` (needs 33 bits). It probably does not fit an `int` on your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner loop always compute `factorial(n)`.

Create sub function may help:

```
int fact(int n)
{
    int res = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        res *= i;
    }
    return res;
}
```

so your main loop becomes:

```
int main()
{
   int n,sum = 0;
   printf("Enter the limit of the factorial series\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
       sum = sum + fact(i); // And now it is evident that it is fact(i) and not fact(n).
   }
   printf("The sum of the factorial series of % d terms is: %d\n", n, sum);
}
```

or if you want to do all in one loop

```
int main()
{
   int n;
   printf("Enter the limit of the factorial series\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   int sum = 0;
   int fact = 1;
   for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
       fact *= i; // update fact, as Fact(n+1) = Fact(n) * (n+1)
       sum += fact;
   }
   printf("The sum of the factorial series of % d terms is: %d\n", n, sum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are always calcultacing `fact(n)` in your second loop. Your second loop should probably be like this :

```
for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
{
    fact = fact * j;
}
```

Comment: You got him right :)